# Scrapy Debug: Redirecting 301 to get

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

After writing my first ?recursive? spider, i face  some problems, i cant get fixed the whole day..

I did research, which misstakes can cause that 301 error, but every solution i tried, didnt help me out yet.

**My console output**
[image: console output]

**My modified settings.py**

```
USER_AGENT = 'kartonage (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0)'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.5
HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

this user_Agent and httperror_allow_all were some solutions for other people with a redirected 301 error

**My modified items.py**

```py
import scrapy


class KartonageItem(scrapy.Item):
    SKU = scrapy.Field()
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Link = scrapy.Field()
    Price = scrapy.Field()
    Delivery_Status = scrapy.Field()
    Weight = scrapy.Field()
    QTY = scrapy.Field()
    Volume = scrapy.Field()
```

**My code i used**

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import KartonageItem

class KartonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kartons12"
    allow_domains = ['karton.eu']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons'
        ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['SKU', 'Title', 'Link', 'Price', 'Delivery_Status', 'Weight', 'QTY', 'Volume'] } 
    
    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.xpath('//div[@class="cat-thumbnails"]')

        for a in url:
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(), callback=self.parse_category_cartons)

    def parse_category_cartons(self, response):
        url2 = response.xpath('//div[@class="cat-thumbnails"]')

        for a in url2:
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(), callback=self.parse_target_page)

    def parse_target_page(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center articelbox"]')

        for a in card:
            items = KartonageItem()
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            items ['SKU'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()').get()
            items ['Title'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="title"]/a/text()').get()
            items ['Link'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="text-center artikelbox"]/a/@href').extract()
            items ['Price'] = a.xpath('.//strong[@class="price-ger price text-nowrap"]/span/text()').get()
            items ['Delivery_Status'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="signal_image status-2"]/small/text()').get()
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(),callback=self.parse_item, meta={'items':items})

    def parse_item(self,response):
        table = response.xpath('//span[@class="product-info-inner"]')

        items = KartonageItem()
        items = response.meta['items']
        items['Weight'] = a.xpath('.//span[@class="staffelpreise-small"]/text()').get()
        items['Volume'] = a.xpath('.//td[@class="icon_contenct"][7]/text()').get()
        yield items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 301 isn't an error, it is a response for [Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). It automatically redirects you to the new address for that page. You can see in your execution logs that you got redirected.

That by itself shouldn't be a problem. Is it something else this may be causing? Any behavior from the spider that is unexpected?

Comment: well then i missunderstood it. Then i'm gonna edit my question